# android update textview of row in listview from Asynctask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

Hi all android developers
I try to perform downloading of content when click on download button and then update Textview of that row in order to show status of download

```
  public OnlineStoreAdapter extends
    ArrayAdapter<MusicDownloadStructure>{ 
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final MusicDownloadStructure data = ModelDownloadData[position];
         .
         .
        Downloadbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            downloadmanager = new ModelDownload(URL, data);
           downloadmanager.execute();
        }
   }
}

public class ModelDownload extends AsyncTask<Object, Long, Boolean> {

     public ModelDownload(String URL, MusicDownloadStructure downloadStructure) {
        connectionurl = URL;
        DownloadStructure = downloadStructure;
    }
     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView statusTextView = DownloadStructure.getStatusTextView();
        statusTextView.setText(TitleStirng);
    }
```

I keep refrence of target Text View in data object and change text in Asynctask but i dont know why text not change nobody can help ?
Tanks

Comment: ur code for updating textview?

Comment: post your async code

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj i post it

Comment: So ModelDownload is downloadmanager? Do you put ModelDownload as nested class (in OnlineStoreAdapter)?

Comment: @BlazeTama Yes modelDownload is  asyntask object but not nested class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `notifyDataSetChanged` :

```
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            ...
            myListView.notifyDataSetChanged(); //or simply notifyDataSetChanged if your Async inside adapter
        }
```